# DNS A/CNAME for two domains with subdomain - how to setup?

Tags: dns, subdomain, cname

Starting over, as I overcomplicated the former description of my problem...

I would like some help to set up the DNS for my two domains so I can access the content from one on the other

I have these two domains: 9juli.dk and splitpoint.dk .

On splitpoint.dk I have a subdomain, 9juli.splitpoint.dk, from which I would like to show the content of on 9juli.dk

Right now it doesn't work. I get a standard page from my provider (Danish Webhosting.dk) when I go to 9juli.dk.

The DNS for 9juli.dk is:
[image: DNS for 9juli.dk]

...and DNS for splitpoint.dk is:
[image: DNS for splitpoint.dk]

I tried some different settings for a records on 9juli.dk to see if I could find out how to make it work.

Comment: This is not something you can do with DNS alone. Your server/hosting needs to be configured to show the correct site for 9juli.splitpoint.dk. If you're getting a default hosting page instead, that's the step you're missing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Tim! I'll try that. If you'll leave your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want 9juli.splitpoint.dk content to be shown as 9juli.dk, correct?

1: configure 9juli.dk as alias to 9juli.splitpoint.dk if your DNS allows that, otherwise use the same IP as 9juli.splitpoint.dk

2: change configuration of your webserver serving 9juli.splitpoint.dk, that virtual host (or just host) should understand 9juli.dk  as an alias to 9juli.splitpoint.dk 
For apache it looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 9juli.splitpoint.dk
        ServerAlias 9juli.dk 
.....
```

The important part is **ServerAlias 9juli.dk**

3: check links in 9juli.dk: if they are pointing to 9juli.splitpoint.dk then you need to modify the site code to use relative links instead of absolute ones, e.g.:

```
<a href="/contact">...  correct link
<a href="http://9juli.splitpoint.dk/contact">...  wrong link
```